# Setting WP7 SystemTray colors in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, system-tray, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to set the SystemTray colors (ForegroundColor & BackgroundColor) in XAML?

It works when I set them in code behind but not in XAML.

I'm using the Mango Beta 2 SDK but there appear to be a number of blog articles which were posted in the timespan of the first beta which report this working with XAML.

I've tested this in the emulator only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the current build [as it seems](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/86462.aspx) that the newer build fixes it. I assume the newer build is internal-only at the moment.

Comment: Confirmed that this is fixed in the Beta2 refresh